# 「ABRT により 問題が検出されました」と表示される

Tags: centos

- クラッシュレポートみたいですが、この結果から分かることはありますか？
  php-fpm プロセスが SIGBUS により強制終了された？
  SIGBUS って何ですか？？
- ABRT 自動報告機能を有効にすると、具体的にどうなるのですか？

---

```
ABRT により 2 件の問題が検出されました。次を実行して詳細を確認してください: abrt-cli list --since 1560381093
# abrt-cli list --since 1560381093
id xxxx
reason:         php-fpm killed by SIGBUS
time:           2019年06月18日 20時52分33秒
cmdline:        'php-fpm: pool www' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
package:        php-fpm-7.2.3-2.el7.remi
uid:            994 (nginx)
count:          2
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-06-18-20:52:33-8410

id xxxx
reason:         php-fpm killed by SIGBUS
time:           2019年06月18日 15時47分35秒
cmdline:        'php-fpm: pool www' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
package:        php-fpm-7.2.3-2.el7.remi
uid:            994 (nginx)
count:          1
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-06-18-15:47:34-8415

自動報告機能は無効になっています。root の特権を持つユーザーで
'abrt-auto-reporting enabled' を発行し、この機能を有効にすることを検討してみてください
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`abrt` とは何かの解説は
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-abrt

提示ログによると `SIGBUS` エラーによって `php-fpm` が抹消されましたとあります。
`SIGBUS` はバスエラーのことで、まあ端的にはプログラムのバグにより処理を継続することができなくなったことを意味します。よくあるのは「ヌルぽ」とか「ヌルり」と呼ばれている、アクセスしてはならない場所をアクセスしたバグです。

```
char* p=NULL;
if (...) p=func();
strcpy(p, data);
```

よくありそうな [c](/questions/tagged/c) コードですが `p` が `NULL` のまま `strcpy()` してしまうバグを含んでいます。 `SIGBUS` はこういうときに発生します。もちろんヌルぽ以外でも `SIGBUS` になることがあります。未初期化ポインタ変数を使ったとかいろいろ。

`CentOS` 自体のバグが疑われる状況では自動報告を有効化することでバグレポートを自動報告できるようです。でも提示のクラッシュレポートが `CentOS` のバグによって発生したのか、あなたの書いたプログラムによって発生したのかはこのログだけではわかりません（後者っぽいですが）まずはあなたの書いた `php-fpm` で呼ばれている `CGI` プログラムのデバッグを検討してみてください。

Comment: 2点疑問があります。疑問1.これまで見たことがない表示だったため大変驚きました。CentOSの仕様が最近変更されたのですか？ それとも単にこれまでこのレベルのクラッシュが発生しなかっただけ(と考えられますか)？？　疑問2.ざっくり言うと、php-fpm プロセスが破棄されるレベルの何らかの負荷が発生したので、原因はphp-fpm ログを確認した方が良い、ということですか？？